# Javascript - "print" mouse on document by cords

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouselistener

I have list of mouse cords `(x,y)`
Because it is impossible to move mouse with javascript, I would like to print a fake mouse on the `document` followed by the cords that I already have.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to print PNG that shows the mouse and hide the original one with css:

```
 createCursor: function() {
                var cursor = document.createElement("img");
                cursor.src = chrome.extension.getURL('pics/cursor.png');
                cursor.style.zIndex = "9999";
                cursor.setAttribute("id", "recordMeCursor");
                var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
                body.style.cursor = 'none';
                body.appendChild(cursor);
            },
 moveCursor: function(cords, i, callback) {
                var cursor = document.getElementById("recordMeCursor");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    cursor.style.position = "absolute";
                    cursor.style.left = cords.x+'px';
                    cursor.style.top =cords.y+'px';
                    return callback('OK');
                }, i * 50);

            },
 destroyMouse: function() {
                var cursor = document.getElementById("recordMeCursor");
                cursor.parentNode.removeChild(cursor);
                var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
                body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
```